# If multiple conditions are met copy offset cell and text

Tags: vba, excel, for-loop, each

I need to check each cell in column "A" and if it `= bci600001178`, and the corresponding cell in column "C" is **9 or less**, then set the cell value to `12600`, and the number from column "C", and `0000`.

If it is `bci600001178`, and the corresponding cell in column "C" is **10 or more**, then set the cell value to `1260`, and the number from column "C", and `0000`.

So if the numbers in column "C" are `10`, `7`, & `15`, I need column "A" to be `1260100000`, `1260070000`, `1260150000`, respectively.

The code below runs but it's outputting only the first value from column "C".  I get `1260100000`, `1260100000`, `1260100000`.

Hopefully this makes sense and someone can help me out. :)

```
Sub Test1()

LastRow = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
Set Item = Range("A3:A" & LastRow)

For Each Cell In Item
    If Cell.Value = "bci60001178" And Cell.Offset(, 2).Value <= 9 Then
    Cell.Value = "12600" & Cell.Offset(, 2).Value & "0000"
    ElseIf Cell.Value = "bci60001178" And Cell.Offset(, 2).Value >= 10 Then
    Cell.Value = "1260" & Cell.Offset(, 2).Value & "0000"
    End If
Next Cell

End Sub
```

Comment: Welcome to [so]! What is your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See if this is what you're looking for...

```
Option Explicit

Sub Test1()

    Dim i As Long, lastRow As Long, ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1)

    lastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, col).End(xlUp).Row

    For i = 3 To lastRow
        If ws.Cells(i, "A").Value = "bci60001178" Then
            Select Case ws.Cells(i, "C").Value
            Case 0 To 9
                ws.Cells(i, "A") = "12600" & ws.Cells(i, "C")
            Case 10 To 99
                ws.Cells(i, "A") = "1260" & ws.Cells(i, "C")
            End Select
        End If
    Next

End Sub
```

I prefer to not use `Offset()` if possible (which it usually is). I got rid of your `For Each` statement and replaced it with a `For i =`.